# how to populate child node in jQuery Treeview in specific parent?

Tags: jquery, treeview

I'm using jQuery Treeview. Is there's a way to populate a children node in a specific parent on onclick event? Please give me some advise or simple sample code to do this.

Comment: codes codes codes (It's not a song)

Comment: which parent? which children? what you want to do...please be more specfic..don't be cruel with us...

Answer (score 0):

You can access the node with Javascript by using

```
document.getElementById('theParent')
    .getElementsByTagName('firstHierarchyTag')[n]
    .getElementsByTagName('secondHierarchyTag')[n]
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, give us the HTML code then we will be able to give a very specific example.

```
// attach the treeview to the main ul
$("#mytree").treeview();

// listen for an event on a specific node
$("#mytreebranch").click(function() {
    var children = "<li><span class='folder'>New Children</span>"+
                   "<ul><li><span class='file'>Sub-child 1</span></li>" + 
                   "<li><span class='file'>Sub-child 2</span></li>" +
                   "</ul></li>";
     children = $(children).appendTo("#mytree");

    // add the new elements to the treeview
    $("#mytree").treeview({
        add: children
    });
});
```